# Как исправить ошибку?

Tags: activity, android

Приложение с таким кодом при запуске вылетает (не показав ничего на экране). В чём проблема и как исправить ошибку?

*MainActivity.java*

```
package dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public TableLayout fl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fldesc);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void fldesc(View v) {
        fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: и логи бы не мешало бы в след. раз выкладывать...

Comment: Есть такая штука, называется LogCat.
Вот там обычно и пишется, что за ошибка возникла, а мало того, чато еще и, в какой строке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вылетает потому, что

```
public TableLayout fl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fldesc);
```

выполняется до вызова метода

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Ты пытаешься найти **TableLayout** на том, что еще даже создано не было